# Hiding drop down arrows in MS Access forms

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am looking for a way to to hide the drop down arrows in fields on a form which refer to list boxes with drop down menus.

Attention, I am not looking to eliminating them, only hiding them until the user arrives on that field. And the has the opportunity to access the drop down menu..   Im not sure what features MS Access 2013 and VBA offer for this type of request, or if it is even possible but was wondering if there are any creative words of wisdom out there..

Thanks,

Comment: Point of clarification:  If it has the drop-down, it isn't a list box.  It is a combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a rectangle to mask the arrow; when the `GotFocus()` event occurs for that control, you can make the rectangle invisible.

Comment: Fantastic Smandoli.. Thank you very much..  Enough of those annoying boxes! Exactly what i was looking for..

Comment: It seems if you cover the drop down Arrow with a rectangle, you dont even need to use code.. upon entering the field, the rectangle disappears and the drop down Arrow is available.

Comment: That is a surprise!  Very nice for you!  It reminds me that sending the rectangle to the "bottom of the stack" is also an option... also known as "move back" versus "move forward", I think.  Maybe that is what you are seeing somehow.

Comment: I didn't describe it very helpfully.  Look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/HV080204924.aspx.  it is odd that Microsoft tags that page 'vba' when it isn't, but it is still the best description I can find at the moment.

Comment: eugh - it's powerpoint all over again. it makes me shudder to think there's no better solution than covering them up.

Comment: It doesn't bother me because this is not a typical use case.  So I say, hooray for Power Point.  Anyway, there are less kludgy solutions... they're just more work to set up.